# Jquery AJAX button call in Umbraco BackOffice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, umbraco

Hi I just created a simple new option for umbraco backoffice, it is a simple html page which displays a button to click.
[Simple form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zswg8.png)

This button should send an ajax call to an UmbracoApi, but the request never reaches the webapi. Below the Api Code:
[API Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhjHQ.png)

The Ajax call is a simple Jquery Ajax call in the event click of the html button.

I'll appreciate any help you can provide me, in order to complete this ajax call.

Comment: show your js code of wire up click and the url you use to send ajax

Comment: Hi @AlanTsai this is the code, it is a simple ajax call
`$("#btnGetData").click(function () {
 $.ajax("http://localhost:44302/umbraco/api/stripebackofficeapi/GenerateLockBoxFile", {
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { date: $('#txtDate').val() },
  cache: false,
  success: function (data, status, headers, config) {
   if (data) {
    alert("Done!");
   }
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, timeout, message) {
   console.log("Error: " + message);
  }
 });
}); `
by now the url is my localhost but in future will be the Umbraco server

Answer (score 0):

I think yor problem is the way you are calling it:

1. not sure if url casing not same as Controller and action will cause routing failure or not, but might as well make then the same
2. you action is binding a primitive type, from my understanding of webapi - primitive type will check at querystring otherwise specifically tell it to look at body
   more info about this, checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

so base on above two statement, try change your call to:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function() {
    $.ajax("http://localhost:44302/Umbraco/Api/StripeBackOfficApi/GenerateLockBoxile?date=" + $('#txtDate').val(), {
            type: "GET"
        }, cache: false, success: function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
                alert("Done!");
            }
        }, error: function(jqXHR, timeout, message) {
            console.log("Error: " + message);
        }
    });
});
```